# How to get punjab/twisted to bypass dns

Tags: dns, xmpp, twisted, punjab

I am trying to get a punjab BOSH server to work with a development XMPP server.  punjab is trying to do a SRV DNS lookup of the XMPP domain, which is not present in our DNS infrastructure.  Is there any way I configure punjab to route requests for "myserver.mydomain.com" to an IP address?  I do not have access to the xmpp:route attribute at the XML-level, so this would have to be done somehow by punjab/twisted configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a quick hack to get you up and running, install [dnsmasq](http://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html), add the following to the config file:

```
srv-host=_xmpp-client._tcp.myserver.mydomain.com,localhost,5222,0
# use your DNS server here instead of 8.8.8.8, which is Google's
server=8.8.8.8
```

Start dnsmasq.  I recommend starting with `sudo dnsmasq -dq` to start with, so you can see the debug output and diagnose any problems.

Modify your network configuration to use 127.0.0.1 as your DNS server.  E.g., but check for your OS, set `resolv.conf` to:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

This will run a small DNS resolver locally on your box, server up the one SRV record locally, and forward everything else to your upstream DNS server.

Comment: I never got to try this, but it seemed like a good idea.  Thanks!

Comment: For me worked the following:

 1) install dnsmasq
 2) add 'nameserver 127.0.0.1' to your /etc/resolve.conf
 3) add '127.0.0.1    mychatdummydomain.com' to your /etc/hosts
 4) service dnsmasq restart